# Jquery open file search windows

Tags: jquery, html

I have create a simple button :

```
<button id="mybutton">Search</button>
```

I need to open the search file window when i click on this button. I need exactly the behavior of input type file.

And i don't want to use an input type file :)

Any idea ? Thanks !

Comment: Why don't you want to use `<input type="file" />` is this a CSS problem ?

Comment: Don't want to use an file input or don't want to *see* it?

Comment: Any attempts yourself? You can use CSS to hide the actual file input and create your own file upload with some tricks.

Comment: I just want to open the search file browser, select a file, and when i click on "OK", retrieve this file and do some stuff.

Comment: @ClémentAndraud: You are not going to be able to access the file, or do anything with it, unless you post it within a form. (or use flash)

Comment: @musefan - HTML5 File API ?

Comment: Can you tell us what you're trying to do (not just "get an open file dailog"), so that we can advise you the best way?

Comment: @adeneo: Huh, I guess you can do some things then... I hope people behave themselves with it though!

Answer (score 1):

You can trigger the click and then listen for the `#file` to change:

```
$(function(){
    $('#mybutton').on('click', function(){
       $("#file").trigger('click'); 
    });
    $("#file").on('change', function(){
       console.log(this.value);
    });
});
```

With `this.value` being the filepath/file

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/L2Qg5/3/)

Comment: best answer so far, but still can't do much with with the file. Plus the path isn't the true path, and still not sure this will work on all browsers either

Comment: @musefan You will never get the true path value.  This is for security reasons.  Also, you can't do anything with the file yourself as it's in a different domain (file://).

Comment: Indeed, some browsers have problems when using `display:none` for file inputs, you should use `position:absolute; top:-100px;`

Comment: @musefan - I agree, and this is the nicest answer so far.  I can't see him getting better.

Comment: @JamieDePalmenaer - Thanks I didn't know that, I'm here to learn too, right?

Comment: @JamieDePalmenaer I'm not :p (JK)

Comment: @F4r-20 You forgot to remove the `display:none;` (And it isn't even 4:20 yet ;D)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want *input file* in your code or you don't want the *input file* style ? In the second case, you can do :

```
$('#inputfile').hide();
$('#mybutton').click(function() {
  $('#inputfile').click();
});
```

Comment: Hum, is there a way to retrieve the "OK" event when i select a file ?

Answer (score 0):

check out this jsfiddle.
You can hide the  field, and bind the button click to the input click.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DSARd/550/)

```
$("#mybutton").click(function () {
    $("#idofinputfield").click();
})
```

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve the "OK" or "Open" event when i slect a file ?

Comment: I think by calling `$("#idofinputfield").change(function() { ... });`

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is an input file "hidden" in the top of the page and call it by your button like this :

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" style="position: absolute; top: -1000px;" />
```

And you call it with jQuery

```
$('#myButton').click(function() {
     $('#file').click();
});
```

And when the file is selected you can know it with

```
$('#file').change(function() {
    // Code here
});
```